# How to convert a weekly dataset into a time series in R

Tags: r

i have a WEEKLY dataset that start on 1986.01.03 and end on 2022-10-07.
The problem is when I forecast the time series with Arima +garch, because the date in T0 is wrong, i.e. 1975 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WskD.png).

The function that I used to convert the dataset into time series is here, but I think that the problem is here, since it doesn't take on the right date.

FutureWeekly= ts(WeeklyFuture$FutureWeekly, start= c(1986,1), end = c(2022,10), frequency = 52)

does anyone know how to convert a weekly dataset to time series other than this?

There are the first rows of my dataset and then I have to transform that into returns (diff(log(FutureWeekly) to do the ARMA+GARCH

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pmze.png)

Comment: Show a few rows of your original dataset and the transformed dataset here, you can use `dput(your-time-series-here)` to do so. It will help us to offer the right answer

Comment: I uploaded a script of the first rows. I Don't understand what you mean with "transformed dataset"

Comment: what kind of data does str(your-df) tell you that the weekly date field is?

Comment: str(WeeklyFuture)
tibble [1,919 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ Date        : POSIXct[1:1919], format: "1986-01-03" "1986-01-10" ...
 $ FutureWeekly: num [1:1919] 23.8 23.6 22.2 20.3 19.9 ...   I runned str function on the original dataset and I obtain this.

Comment: Do you have a full 52 week-periods without missing values?

Comment: this I don't know how to understand it.
I downloaded the data directly weekly from the site and loaded in R adjusting the dataset from 1986.  EIAhttps://www.eia.gov/dnav/pet/hist/LeafHandler.ashx?n=PET&s=RCLC4&f=W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
futures<-c(WeeklyFuture$FutureWeekly) #convert to vector
FutureWeekly= ts(futures, start= c(1986,1,10), end = c(1986,3,7), frequency = 52) #add day of week ending on
```

One of the things `ts()` demands is a vector of values. I think it might also be easier for `ts()` to convert the data if it was able to see the 7-day increments.

Assuming you have full un-broken weekly data for the entire period, I think these two things will solve the problem.